# Android - call "finish()" does not trigger onDestroy

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-lifecycle

I have 3 activities. And I want to do something like this:

A   ->  on button press ->   B    ->   on button press ->   (destroy A, B) create C

Everything works, but I noticed some "strange" behaviour in  the logs of Android Studio.

When I press the button on activity A this is done:

```
I/System.out: The A Activity is onStart. 
I/System.out: The A Activity is onResume. 
I/System.out: The A Activity is onPause. 
I/System.out: The B Activity is onResume. 
I/System.out: The A Activity is stopped.
```

Then I press the button again  on activity B:

```
I/System.out: The B Activity is paused.
I/System.out: The B Activity is stopped.
```

and I enter in activity C. But on the console is not written that activity A and B are destroyed, even if I call the method finish() in activity B.

Just, when from the activity C I press the back button this is executed.

```
I/System.out: The B Activity is destroyed.
I/System.out: The A Activity is destroyed.
```

And I automatically exit the app.

My question is:
**Why this was not triggered when I pressed the button on the activity B?**

B class:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, C.class));
```

B on stop:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
    finish();

    super.onStop();

    System.out.println("The B Activity is stopped.");
}
```

A class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1){
        finish();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another strange thing, when I press the button in the activity B, I go in the activity C, and the activity B onStop is executed.

But:

1. As I said finish() does not trigger
2. setResult() does not trigger activities A "onActivityResult"

When is setResult() triggered? together with onDestroy()?

**EDIT 2**

If you read the comments, another interesting question came up.

Why the onDetroy() method does not get called when finish() gets called from onStop()?; and when the finish() method is out of onStop(), the onDestroy() gets normally called.

Is it normal/by design?

Comment: As far as I know, `onDestroy` is called at "some point" in the future, not immediately upon `finish()`

Comment: this^
Check out [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) part for more information

Comment: @Vucko I did... but could not find answers to my questions... btw, tnx, great link!

Comment: i sense sarcasm :D

Comment: @Vucko  everything but not my answer :D ... no really, nice info there!

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a simple test app. Every time I call finish(), the activity goes through onDestroy immediately even if it started an activity for a result.  Do you have anything special in the manifest for any of these activities?  Have you tried also making an extremely simple test app to reproduce this?

Comment: @DougStevenson I found the reason why my activity B was not destroyed after I call finish(). I simply moved out finish() from onStop Method, and copied it in my "normal" code, and then B was destroyed.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't know why was not called from onStop().
The activity A ondestroy gets called just in the moment I press back from activity C .... Does not show the activity A , but gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Activities are on a stack so when you start a new activity from one, the old is not destroyed, it will be kept on the stack cause normally you will come back to it in the lifecycle of your app, by pressing "back-button".
2. When you want a result of a triggered Activity, you must call startActivityForResult
3. onDestroy is triggered when the activity is no longer needed which is a decision of the android framework and you can not really know, when this happens, since android guess its a good chance you will come back to it in your apps lifecycle. It depends on used memory and the distance to navigate to it, just an optimization of constructing activities to avoid laggy behavior.

Comment: Tnx! One more question. I was thinking that when the activity B makes setResult() the activity A onActivityResult will automatically get called even if activity C was launched , but is not like this.... I notices that onActivityResult will be executed when the user actually returns on the activity A, and then before every other method this onActivityResult() method gets executed. That's why I saw ondestroy just at the moment I was supposed to go back to activity A. Am I right?

Comment: yes thats right, you have to go back to the activity which calls "startActivityForResult"

Comment: The statement in #1 is not true.  You can definitely force a finish an activity and destroy it with other activities on top of it.  This is how splash screen activities normally work (you don't want to go "back" to a splash screen).  Android will also destroyed activities in the stack if it needs resources - the activity will be recreated if the user goes back to it.

Comment: one more thing that I can't understand.... Why in activity B, if I put finish() out of my onStop() method, the onDestroy() gets executed immediately after C gets present on the screen? and if I leave the finish() in onStop() , the destroy() B  gets called when I destroy the activity C?

Comment: @ Doug Stevenson : how you destroy it definitely? Of course a splash screen seems unreachable after startup so the framework can see there is no path to it in the rest of app lifecycle. Can you clear it to me?

Comment: It depends i think, if you call "forResult" to create it or not. Seems its just waiting for the activity stack to pass something back to it before it ends.

Comment: @HenningLuther so normally the code that I write in onStop(), even if I call finish() should get executed without any problems? right?

Comment: @HenningLuther I upvoted, but maybe cause I don't have big reputation you cannot see... I am not sure

Comment: calling finish in onStop is not recommended in my opinion, you delete the activity in the stack and the real history is gone. of course if it is exactly what you want , yes

Comment: i never saw a usecase deleting an activity when it gets stopped by starting another one, worse when you expect results or handle your apps lifecycle properly

Comment: @HenningLuther tnx, in fact I tried to make some other simple code, just to see if, when I put finish() in onStop(), the onDestroy() will be called... but it does not get called. And when I put finish() out of onStop() the onDestroy is normally called

Comment: @HenningLuther so this is normal/by design?

Comment: this is a good question, i think this is a thing deep down in the android framework which i never recognized/faced. perhaps you should put this clearly in your primary question to focus on that. i upvote it now cause i think its a good question, i dont have a good answer for it and could just guess

Comment: This answer expect app to be written in some way but its not how they have to be. Some apps have just one activity, not a stack and also, when you read documentation it is clearly stated in activity onDestroy that it gets called after finish and some other important details... but I also have som issues with this, still investigating...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your "Edit 2", the onDestroy() actually does get called when you leave the screen till it gets black, or when you simply press shut down botton to turn the screen off.

As @Henning Luther mentioned, the answer is maybe somewhere deep in Android, and have possibly to do also with the surface and other things also...

If I put finish() out of onStop(), it gets normally destroyed.

*it is not a completly answer but since I cannot put comments I did it in this way, cause wanted to share it

Comment: tnx! you are right, I tried it and I can confirm that this happens also for me....btw interesting thing. I upvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues also, that i found that after calling finish on activity onDestroy and also listener `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityDestroyed` where not called. How-where when I checked out docs it looks like they should:

Activity.onDestory documentations says:

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can
> happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called
> finish() on it), or because the system is temporarily destroying this
> instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between
> these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method....

But I found that isFinishing also was not true.

Solution on my end was simply to wait with code that rely on activity onDestroy to be called by using: `Handler.postDelayed` running on main thread, also you can use view `post(Runnable action)` that do the same thing.